# How to migrate a single workitem in Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I am doing TFS to Devops migration and for that I am running a JSON file. FOr testing I thought to migrate a single Epic(for example epic number 123). IS it possible to migrate single item and the items below this. TO make it run, what WIQLQueryBit I should write?

```
    "WIQLQueryBit": "AND  [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Epic = 123')",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you are using [this Migration Tool](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools). I checked [the document](https://nkdagility.com/learn/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/v1/Processors/WorkItemMigrationContext/) and found this

> #### WIQL Query Bits
>
> The Work Item queries are all built using Work Item Query Language (WIQL).

> Note: A useful Azure DevOps Extension to explore WIQL is the [WIQL Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor).
> You can use the WIQL Editor to craft a query in Azure DevOps.

My test steps of the extension:

1. create and save a query to query the epic ID 324

[image]

2. After installing the extension, choose the Edit query wiql option.

[image]

3. It shows the wiql of the query.

[image]

4. The result you need in the "WIQLQueryBit"

```
    "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Epic' AND [System.Id] = 324"
```